# using xlwt to edit excel file then save it, but get nothing changed

Tags: excel, xlwt

I am a new learner.Maybe it's A Stupid Question. I use below code try to write something in sheet :'new' in 'or.xlsx'. but after i finised ran my code. nothing was been writer in that sheet. No error was pop up.Here is the code :

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
import xlwt
wb = xlwt.Workbook('D:\Work\xxx\xx\python\or.xlsx')
ws = wb.add_sheet(u'new', cell_overwrite_ok=True)
ws.write(0, 0, u'523123')
wb.save('or.xlsx')
```

IDE: Pycharm
python 2.7.13

Answer (score 0):

drop the first line, `xlrd` is not used in the remainder of the code.

xlwt writes XLS files, not XLSX.

The first arg of xlwt.Workbook is NOT a file path! Pls review the docs.